# Mean and median distance in unweighted graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have a very large graph of ~7 million vertices and ~100 million edges. One dfs run in my current implementation runs in 30 seconds.   The graph is an unweighted directed strongly connected graph.

I need to find the mean and median distances of the graph (median and mean distances over all shortest-path distances of the graph). I need the exact mean/median, not an approximation. This problem must be related to all-pairs shortest paths. But the only algorithms I know of for this problem are: Floyd Warshall, Dijkstra starting from each vertex, and Breadth First Search starting from each vertex. However, their running time is $\Omega(V^2)$ for all three of these algorithms, so for such a large graph they are too slow.

Can this problem be solved in linear or linearithmic time?  If not, what is the fastest algorithm for this problem, in asymptotic complexity?

Comment: 1. I wonder if research on "distance oracles" or preprocessing a graph to support fast distance queries might be useful somehow.  See, e.g., http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8703/5038, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/11518/5038,  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8911/5038.  Approximate distance oracles probably won't be useful, and I don't know if much is known about exact oracles. 2. Is the diameter of this graph small, compared to $V$?  Is the mean/median small compared to $V$?  I don't know if that might help design a faster algorithm, if it is known/expected to be small.

Comment: Yes, it is very short (though I kinda supposed to find it myself too) - I was also going to ask the next question here about diameter =) But the graph diameter from their data = 15. But I kinda dont know how it can be useful at all. Thx for links though.

Comment: Can you share with us the source of this problem/exercise?

Comment: For diameter, see [Theorem 1](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos528/RodittyWilliamsDiameter.pdf) and the ​ "We prove Theorem 1 by showing that an ... reason." ​ part of that paper. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is not a full answer.)

The median distance is necessarily an integer [footnote 1].  Therefore, it might be possible to use an approximation algorithm for the median to compute the *exact* median, if the approximation is sufficiently precise.

Suppose the true median is $\xi$.  Then if we can efficiently compute a $1+1/3\xi$-approximation to the median, we can reconstruct the exact median from that.

I suspect it is possible to get a $\tau$-approximation to the median efficiently through random sampling.  In particular, consider the following procedure:

- Repeat $k$ times: in the $i$th iteration, pick a random vertex $v_i$, compute single-source shortest paths from $v_i$ to every vertex, and find the distribution of these distances.
- Aggregate these distributions and output the median of this aggregated distribution.

One might hope to get an approximation whose quality increases rapidly with $k$, and where if we want a constant approximation factor $\tau$, then a constant $k$ suffices.  I have no proof that this is possible, though.

We can consider a simpler situation, where given an integer $x$ we are trying to approximately count the fraction of distances that are at most $x$.  If the fraction of such distances is approximately $1/2$ (e.g., because $x$ is approximately the median), then one approach is random sampling: repeat $k$ times where we pick a random pair of vertices $u,v$ and compute the distance from $u$ to $v$ (say using BFS), then count what fraction of those $k$ distances are at most $x$.  The additive error is typically about $1/2\sqrt{k}$; it exceeds $c/\sqrt{k}$ with probability exponentially small in $c$ (it's basically the probability of a Gaussian being more than $2c$ standard deviations away from the mean).  Thus, we can get a $1+\epsilon$-approximation to this count using $O(1/\epsilon^2)$ iterations.  Each iteration takes at most $O(E)$ time, so with $O(E/\epsilon^2)$ time we can get a $1+\epsilon$-approximation to this count.  The probability that our approximation is wrong can be made exponentially small; an error probability of $1/2^{100}$ is so small as to be negligible in practice (e.g., it is smaller than the probability of a cosmic ray causing a bitflip error that causes an error in your code), and this will increase the running time by only a constant factor (say, 100, or something like that).  In this case it might be sufficient to also take $\epsilon$ to be a small constant.

Intuitively, it feels like if we can get a good approximation to this count, it might be possible to extend this to a good approximation to the median.  For instance, if we hypothesize that the median is $x$, we can count the fraction of distances that are $\le x-1$, the fraction that are $\le x$, and the fraction that are $\le x+1$.  If $x$ is indeed the median, hopefully the first fraction will be noticeably smaller than $1/2$ and the latter fraction will be noticeably larger than $1/2$.  I don't know how to turn this into an algorithm that I can prove will always work on all graphs, but I suspect this might work well enough in practice.

---

Computing the (exact) mean seems like it might be harder, as the mean isn't necessarily an integer.

---

Footnote 1: The median is either an integer or halfway between two integers.  In the latter case, the rest of the answer carries through if you divide everything by two.

Comment: Why is the median distance necessarily an integer? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, the median of a bunch of integers is always an integer.  Each distance is an integer (since we're dealing with an unweighted graph), and the question asks us to compute the median of $V^2$ of these integers.  Or have I overlooked something?

Comment: {1,2} is a set of integers whose median is not an integer. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, I guess it depends how you want to define the median.  Under one definition, the median of {1,2} is either 1 or 2 (they're both medians).  Under a different definition, the median of {1,2} is 1.5.  If you prefer the former definition, the median is always an integer.  If you prefer the latter definition, the median is always an integer or a half-integer (i.e., integer plus 0.5), and the rest of the answer carries through (dividing everything by 2).

Comment: Although it makes sense to define the median in other ways, the standard is to compute the mean of the two "median" values. I would just rewrite that first paragraph with the details of your comment, because it sounds weird.